# css calc expression is marked as invalid with flex-box

Tags: css, less, flexbox

This is my less script:

```
@info-box: 185px;


.info {
  width: ~"calc(100%-@{info-box})";

}
```

Less compiled it as expected to `width: calc(100%-185px);

However chrome marks this expression as invalid.

[image]

I want to know if it has anything to do with `flex-box` display mode

I have used the calc formula for `max-width` and I got the same result.

If I set the `width` or `max-width` to a numeric value, the problem goes away.

Comment: Are you sure you spaced the minus `-` on both sides?

Comment: Oh, I think it is the answer! Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: That's great that it was painless and simple, I provided an answer, sir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there's space on both sides of the operator when using `calc`

```
calc(100% - 12px)
         ^-^------------The `calc` property is very particular
           about the spacing of the operator. (e.g. - + / *)
```

It used to drove me nuts when it would work sometimes but not other times. Then I read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/).